# vim could load not tcl86.dll

Tags: windows, vim, dll, tcl

Yesterday I built gvim (7.4.552, 32-bit) on Windows XP with +tcl +lua +python, MinGW make gave a few error messages about tcl lib (I'm using ActiveTcl8.6.3), but still gvim.exe was created.

I tried lua and tcl and everything worked as expected. But today gvim said it could not load library tcl86.dll. I had not changed anything to the system, and tcl86.dll is on search path. This is so confusing I don't even know where to look at.

This is my build command:

```
mingw32-make.exe -f Make_ming.mak LUA="d:/Lua/5.1" LUA_VER=52 TCL="D:/Tcl" TCL_VER=86 PYTHON="D:/Python27" PYTHON_VER=27 DYNAMIC_PYTHON=yes PYTHON3="D:/Python33" PYTHON3_VER=33 DYNAMIC_PYTHON3=yes FEATURES=HUGE GUI=yes gvim.exe
```

Comment: Do you mean could not load?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say "could not load."

Comment: Figured it out myself. Copy zlib1.dll to $VIMRUNTIME. This zlib1.dll needs to be the one installed side by side with tcl86.dll, others (like the one of MinGW) won't do, even they have the same version.

Comment: You should write that up as a proper answer. Self-answering is encouraged here!

Answer (score 1):

From os_win32.c, I built a tiny exe to load tcl86.dll, the error message pointed to zlib1.dll. A search showed there was a copy in c:\windows\system32, it was of lower version and smaller size than the one in tcl/bin.

Copying tcl/bin/zlib1.dll to $VIMRUNTIME solved the problem. Or, even better I thought, just delete the one in windows/system32.